# Android: intent.putExtra in a Service Class to get notifications

Tags: android, service, android-intent

This is my showNotification method in the **Service class**:

```
private void showNotification() {

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
"New Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent i = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
i.putExtra("notification", "MyNotif");
i.putExtra("notifiedby", "NotedBy");
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "NotedBy", "MyNotif", contentIntent);
nm.notify(111, notification);
}
```

so after clicking on the **Notification** from the **status bar**, i will end up in **myActivity**.

The problem is these lines always gives **false** in the myActivity.

```
this.getIntent().hasExtra("notification")
this.getIntent().hasExtra("notifiedby")
```

**Doesn't putExtra() work with PendingIntent??**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
String notification = getIntent().getStringExtra("notification");
String notifiedby = getIntent().getStringExtra("notifiedby");
```

Comment: Yeah even i figured it out. If i remove 'this' it works fine. You have any idea why so?? Thank You

Comment: I dont know how you have handled your code but sometimes 'this' might be referring to the wrong context. If you don't provide anything, android will take the default context of your current activity and you get the correct result.