# Notification service put extra on notification click, how?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-service, android-notifications

Well I have a service that runs with a notification, I want to put an extra with the new intent opened when the user clicks the notification, so when `MainActivity` opens I can get the extra. I have tried with different ways, but I just don't find how to get it to work.

Here's what I have tried:

This is MyService

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyService.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("EXTRA", StringTEST);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent
                        .getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                                     0, intent, 0);
```

this opens the activity fine, but I can't get the extra?? This is how I have tried to get it:

MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        String name = extras.getString("EXTRA");
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    System.out.println(extras+"");
    if (extras != null) {
        try {
            onNewIntent(getIntent());
            Intent i = getIntent();
            String name = i.getStringExtra("EXTRA");
            System.out.println(name);
            currentDir = new File(name);

            changeFiles();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Those are the two ways I have tried, but I still get null... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 32):

I'm guessing that your problem is here:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                           0, intent, 0);
```

You are passing `intent` to `getActivity()` and expecting that you will get back a `PendingIntent` that matches your `Intent` and includes your extras. Unfortunately, if there is already a `PendingIntent` floating around in the system that matches your `Intent` (**without** taking into consideration your `Intent` extras) then `getActivity()` will return you that `PendingIntent` instead.

To see if this is the problem, try this:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                           0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This says that if there is already a `PendingIntent` that matches your `Intent` somewhere in the system that it should replace the extras with the ones in your `intent` parameter.

Comment: Tried this and I didn't get it either, but I managed to got it to work making it a `static String` I know is not the best way, but...

Comment: Glad you got it working. I still don't understand what the problem is. Maybe you'll figure it out. If you do, please answer your own question so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: This helped in my case. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it is possible to get different extras into multiple notification

Comment: @flipperweid There are many questions on stackoverflow about this. Just look. Basically you need to ensure your `PendingIntent` is unique. You can do that by using a unique `requestCode` in each call to `PendingIntent.getActivity()` or you can set a unique ACTION on each `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Hi, yes I use that. My comment was meant only as a "thank you!:-)" , cause before I use the 'FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT every clicked Notification had the same extras altough I had set different extras in different notifications. Now it work's:-))

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You used `getIntent().getExtras()` but you should have used `getIntent().getStringExtra(id)`.
It's mentioned here too:  [Android: intent.putExtra in a Service Class to get notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820556/android-intent-putextra-in-a-service-class-to-get-notifications)

Also it's considered not to be a good practice to use static variables as you've mentioned in your comment, I'd suggest to avoid it.

Comment: To my surprise, it actually worked, however, I was casting it to string in the other case.